# mysql multiple unions to multiple left joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've been trying to change a query containing multiple unions, to a query containing multiple left joins.

The union query was

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,typ
FROM   (SELECT user_id,
           'review' AS typ
    FROM   review
    WHERE  time > '2011-12-01'

    UNION

    SELECT user_id,
           'invite' AS typ
    FROM   invite
    WHERE  time_created > '2011-12-01'
            OR time_action > '2011-12-01'

    UNION

    SELECT user_id,
           'voter' AS typ
    FROM   vote
    WHERE  time > '2011-12-01'

    UNION

    SELECT user_id,
           'voted' AS typ
    FROM   review
    WHERE  review_id IN (SELECT object_id
                         FROM   vote
                         WHERE  vote = 1
                                AND type = 'review'
                                AND time > '2011-12-01')

    UNION

    SELECT user_id,
           'comment' AS typ
    FROM   comment
    WHERE  time > '2011-12-01'

    UNION

    SELECT user_id,
           'joined' AS typ
    FROM   USER
    WHERE  updated_time > '2011-12-01'
            OR last_login_date > '2011-12-01'

    UNION

    SELECT user_id,
           'wishlist' AS typ
    FROM   user_wishlist
    WHERE  time > '2011-12-01'

    UNION

    SELECT introducer,
           'introducer' AS typ
    FROM   introduction
    WHERE  time > '2011-12-01'

    UNION

    SELECT user_id,
           'answer' AS typ
    FROM   answer
    WHERE  time > '2011-12-01') T
WHERE  T.user_id IN (SELECT user_id
                 FROM   USER
                 WHERE  user_id < 5245762)
```

which I've been able to change to something like this:

```
SELECT t1.user_id,
   IF(t2.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS review,
   IF(t3.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS invite,
   IF(t4.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS voter,
   IF(t5.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS voted,
   IF(t6.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS comment,
   IF(t7.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS joined,
   IF(t8.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS wishlist,
   IF(t9.user_id, 'yes', 'no')  AS introducer,
   IF(t10.user_id, 'yes', 'no') AS answer

FROM   (SELECT user_id
    FROM   user
    WHERE  user_id < 5245762) t1

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   review
              WHERE  time > '2011-12-01') t2

          ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   invite
              WHERE  time_created > '2011-12-01'
                      OR time_action > '2011-12-01') t3

          ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   vote
              WHERE  time > '2011-12-01') t4

          ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   review
              WHERE  review_id IN (SELECT object_id
                                   FROM   vote
                                   WHERE  vote = 1
                                          AND type = 'review'
                                          AND time > '2011-12-01')) t5

          ON t1.user_id = t5.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   comment
              WHERE  time > '2011-12-01') t6

          ON t1.user_id = t6.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   user
              WHERE  updated_time > '2011-12-01'
                      OR last_login_date > '2011-12-01') t7

          ON t1.user_id = t7.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   user_wishlist
              WHERE  time > '2011-12-01') t8

          ON t1.user_id = t8.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT introducer AS user_id
              FROM   introduction
              WHERE  time > '2011-12-01') t9

          ON t1.user_id = t9.user_id

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
              FROM   answer
              WHERE  time > '2011-12-01') t10

          ON t1.user_id = t10.user_id
```

Now i know the results of both queries would be a little different, the first query used to provide results like

```
user_id    typ
```

---

```
1          invite
2          invite
1          voter
1          voted
2          voted
```

The left join query provides result like

```
user_id    invite    voter     voted
```

---

```
1           yes       yes        yes
2           yes       no         yes
```

Now when the list of user_id is approximately less than 500 (last WHERE in union query and table t1 in left join query), the left join query is faster, afterwards, the union query is faster. But after running the left join query I figured the union query was missing data of some users (no rows of that user_id) whereas the left join query provided accurate results. Is there a way I can make my left join query faster than the union one? Or fix my union query to provide results accurately?

PS: The WHERE (T.user_id in ... in union query) (SELECT user_id from user ... in left join query) condition which is providing user_id is just an example over here, it can be a custom query from multiple tables providing a column of user_ids with multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

You should use "EXPLAIN" in front of your mysql query. It will show the mysql execution plan for the query and also possible performance bottle necks.

See mysql rerefence: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Explain works only for select queries but not update or delete.

We cannot give you more hints than that because you did not post the database schema defintions for your tables which would show which field types you are using and what keys are defined.